# Configuration Error Nginx + ExpressGateway + Express API + Socket.io

Tags: express, nginx, socket.io, express-gateway

I'm having very difficult times trying to make this work, I have a microservice architecture in place that support multiple areas of the business, now I would like to add a new microservice that will expose a socket connection to serve some realtime information to the apps.
Check the image below:

[image: app architecture]

I will share some aspects here to see if you can help me to fix this configuration issue.

I did some tests to identify where the issue is being caused, I did a test connecting directly to the Node API (running on the server) without using the Nginx and the ExpressGateway, check the Gif below everything works as expected:

[See how it worked](https://gifyu.com/image/nM3V)

It makes the 'polling' connection and then upgrade to Websocket that is what we want, received the messages and not make any new connections.

This is the API server configuration:

```
constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.initExpress();
        this.initExpressMiddleWare();
        this.dvConn = new DAO();
        this.server = this.start();
        this.io = io().attach(this.server, {
            path: `${config.BASE_PATH}`,
            origins: '*:*',
            transports:['polling', 'websocket'],
            serveClient: false
        });
        this.newSocketUsers = [];
        this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log(`a user connected ${socket.id}`);
            const user_id = this.decode_id(socket.handshake.query.user_id).toString();
            const socket_id = socket.id;
            this.registerConnection(socket_id, user_id);
            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                console.log(`a user disconnected ${socket.id}`);
                const socket_id = socket.id;
                this.unRegisteredConnection(socket_id);
            });
        });
```

And this is the part of an Angular client App to test this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = http;
    this.socket = io('http://dev.server.com:3033', {
      query: {
        user_id: '988379518723645912'
      },
      transports: ['polling', 'websocket']
    });
    this.socket.on('reconnect_attempt', () => {
      this.socket.io.opts.transports = ['polling', 'websocket'];
    });
  }

  connect(): void {
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Opening Connection');
    });
  }
```

Now the problem comes when this run through Nginx and the ExpressGateway, see the Gif below to see how the application first logs a 502 error, and it continues polling and never upgrade to WebSocket, making that with every new message sent it logs that as a new polling request:

[See how it doesn't worked](https://gifyu.com/image/nM9z)

I did my homework and I know some configuration is needed on Nginx, this is my Nginx.conf configuration:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        client_max_body_size 12m;
        client_body_buffer_size 16k;
        server_name dv3.synth5.orcasnet.com api.orcasnet.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCMsssssss';
        location /  {
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                proxy_connect_timeout 10080s;
                proxy_send_timeout 10080;
                proxy_read_timeout 10080;
                proxy_buffer_size 64k;
                proxy_buffers 16 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass    http://gateway.domain.net:3020;
        }
}
```

And the last is the ExpressGateway policy configuration:

```
socStg:
    apiEndpoints:
      - socStg
    policies:
      - cors:
      - log:
        - action:
            message: ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} ${req.headers}
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: socStg
              changeOrigin: true
              ws: true
              timeout: 120000
```

I would appreciate any help you can provide me with this problem, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer Express-Gateway doesn't support socket connections, I needed to deploy the API directly with Nginx. Now is working.

Answer (score 0):

following doc contain event as socket..

https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/plugins/plugin-development/

```
module.exports = {
  version: '1.2.0',
  init: function (pluginContext) {
    pluginContext.eventBus.on('hot-reload', function ({ type, newConfig }) {
      // "type" is gateway or system
      // depends on what file was changed
      // newConfig - is newly loaded configuration of ExpressGateway
      console.log('hot-reload', type, newConfig);
    });

    pluginContext.eventBus.on('http-ready', function ({ httpServer }) {
      console.log('http server is ready', httpServer.address());

      // Proxy websockets to localhost:9015
      const httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
      var proxy = new httpProxy.createProxyServer({
        target: {
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 9015
        }
      });

      httpServer.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
        proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
      });
    });

    pluginContext.eventBus.on('https-ready', function ({ httpsServer }) {
      console.log('https server is ready', httpsServer.address());
    });

    pluginContext.eventBus.on('admin-ready', function ({ adminServer }) {
      console.log('admin server is ready', adminServer.address());
    });
  }
}
```